# How can i run a task at particular time ? I need to silent the phone at the user given time

Tags: android

I need to silent the phone at a particular time.The time is given by the user.
I am new to android.

Comment: `I am new to android` - and StackOverflow it would seem, suggest you edit your question following these guidelines : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to set alarm manager:

```
private void settingAlarmManager (){

int requestCode = 12345

            calendar.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth - 1, selectedDay, selectedHour, selectedMinutes, 0); // For giving Date and Time for alert \\
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(AddTaskActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddTaskActivity.this,
                    requestCode, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, broadcast);

        }
```

Here is the manifest Code:

```
<receiver android:name=".alarm.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Here is the Alarm Receiver class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //am.setRingerMode(0); // For Silent \\
        am.setRingerMode(1); // For Vibrate \\
        //am.setRingerMode(2); // For Ringer \\

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for triggering event at specified time and use [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) for changing the ringer mode like this:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```